# Schema for One-to-Many relationship for fast lookup of the many

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

Data I am looking to create an SQLite database for:

```
(ID_1, 0, 0)
(ID_2, 0, 0)
(ID_3, 1, 1)
(ID_1, 1, 1)
(ID_2, 1, 1)
(ID_3, 2, 2)
...
```

Triples of IDs then two integers. About 200M+ IDs that may be repeated many times, and each might be associated with between 1 and >10,000,000 different pairs of two integers.

I have two operations to perform :

1. Adding to this database, frequently. Every few seconds about 1000 new data points (ID, First Integer, Second Integer) and this needs to complete reasonably fast.
2. Lookup an id like `ID_1` and get a list of all pairs of integers associated with it - in this case (0, 0) and (1, 1). This is the main lookup operation and I want it to be fast.

I am trying to figure out one-to-many relationships. How to design my tables so that these two operations work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to help you but I am not sure if you have tried anything at all. For a simple problem like you have (magnitude is the only issue here, not the complexity), you need only one table and one index

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS triples (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    tid TEXT, 
    pair1 INT, 
    pair2 INT
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_tid ON triples (tid);
```

I created a db like above and inserted 13M rows just for kicks using random ints for `pair1` and `pair2`. Selecting random IDs takes a few milliseconds which meets your criteria of 'very quickly'

Good luck